# Maven custom version best practices

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, tortoisesvn, versioning

I'm looking to improve the way I manage versions in maven so I can see the version in my application interface and MANIFEST file. Currently I have in my root pom.xml these properties:

```
<properties>
   <build.number>268</build.number>
    <svn.revision>10096</svn.revision>
    <jira.version>1.0.19</jira.version>
    <project.web.version>${jira.version}.${svn.revision}_${build.number}</project.web.version>
</properties>
```

In my EAR pom.xml I added these properties to MANIFEST file:

```
<manifest>
    <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
    </manifest>
    <archive>
        <manifestEntries>
            <Specification-Title>${project.name}</Specification-Title>
            <Specification-Version>${svn.revision}</Specification-Version>
            <Implementation-Version>${build.number}</Implementation-Version>
        </manifestEntries>
    </archive>
```

In web module pom.xml I use a plugin that replace the version in a script from which the version will be displayed in application interface with the value from project.web.version.

```
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>replace</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <ignoreMissingFile>true</ignoreMissingFile>
        <file>${basedir}\src\main\webapp\Commons\Libraries\jsAppVersion.js</file>
        <token>(\").*?(\")</token>
        <regex>true</regex>
        <value>"${project.web.version}"</value>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Set the values with maven: package -Dbuild.number=277 -Dsvn.revision=10235 -Djira.version=1.0.20
Any ideas to improve that?

Comment: You could probably [lookup the svn version of the working copy](http://www.zorched.net/2006/07/20/getting-the-revision-number-of-your-subversion-working-copy/) rather than passing it in

Comment: there are some plugins which allows you to get svn version, i'm sure there is something for managing build number. so i recommend you to search for right plugins

Comment: I would suggest to take a look at the [buildnumber-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/) to get the information from version control (SVN or Git) etc. The build number should be handled by the appropriate CI server like Jenkins and get this information in an automated way as well...